# Menu items - onclick FadeInDown and FadeOutUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

- I have a menu composed of three options.
- Clicking on one causes a container `div` to "FadeInDown".
- Then, its contents "FadeIn".
- Clicking on another menu item or anywhere else on the page causes the
  contents to "FadeOut" then container `div` to "FadeOutUp".

Here is the fiddle that I have been testing [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EOrduna/awmat/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        animationHover(this,'.fadeInDown');
    });
});
```

I'm not very familiar with jQuery and have been trying to use animate-css to get me along. Thanks for any help and tips in advance and welcome coding criticism :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is mainly based on JQuery and its `animate` function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) . Here is the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/awmat/7/

I use JavaScript objects like `fadeInDown` to animate the container.

```
var fadeInDown = {
    opacity:1,
    top: "50px"
};
```

And i use the `complete` callback function of `animate` to make the content appear after the container.

To manage several div (one for each menu item), I use id as selectors, but since the "click and display" function remains the same, I used a "builder" : (this uses a closure, so if you're not familiar with JavaScript, you may have to read several times to understand what is going on)

```
var menuClickCallbackBuilder = function(menuItem){
    var container = $('#container' + menuItem);
    var content = container.find('.content');

    var showContent = function(){
        content.animate({opacity:1},{duration:1000});
    };

    return function() {
        var activeContainer = $('.active');
        var hideContainer = function(){
           activeContainer.animate(fadeOutUp,1000);
        };
        activeContainer.find('.content').animate({opacity:0},{duration: 1000, complete : hideContainer});
        activeContainer.removeClass("active");

        if(activeContainer[0] != container[0])
        {
            var timeout = activeContainer[0] ? 2000 : 0 ;
            setTimeout(function(){
                 container.animate(fadeInDown,{duration : 1000, complete :showContent});
            },timeout);  

            container.addClass("active");
        } 
    }
};
```

This way, when you add the add the click callbacks, you can just do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // note that menuClickCallbackBuilder(1) returns a function
    // again if you're not familiar with JS, you may have to re-read menuClickCallbackBuilder
    $('#menuLink1').on('click', menuClickCallbackBuilder(1)); 
    $('#menuLink2').on('click', menuClickCallbackBuilder(2));
    $('#menuLink3').on('click', menuClickCallbackBuilder(3));
});
```

**Some improvements you can bring to this** :

- Factor the durations into a variable (e.g `animationDurationInSeconds`) so that if you want to change the speed of the animation, you only have 1 thing to change. (@Huangism: and right after you did that, make animation faster so that it gets more dynamic)
- (From @Huangism) : stop it from going crazy when people cicks on the menu 10 times really fast
- Actually, I think you don't need 3 different containers, you could do it with just one container (though I don't know if it would be considered an improvement)
- There is probably a way to use CSS classes instead of `fadeInDown` and `fadeOutUp` JS objects. That would be cleaner, I think you should keep styles in CSS as much as you can.
- There is no need for different IDs for menu items, you could do the exact same thing with a loop.
- Whatever your imagination wants to add

Comment: Hi! Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! Except that each menu has their own div.Will your method be functional across all browsers?

Comment: Ok let me some time to get something working. Tell me if you have questions about how it works

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you Paul! I'll keep you updated and ask questions if I read it through and yet still don't understand

Comment: while this looks cool and the answer is good. just make sure you(OP) implement something to stop it from going crazy when people cicks on the menu 10 times really fast. also the fades causes the perceived speed of the site to be slow

Comment: @Huangism : indeed, adding your (very good) remarks as "improvements", so that OP has quick access to it.

Comment: @Huangism ah, I didn't factor in the effects firing multiple times. Yes the first thing I have done is adjust the speed, there is nothing more annoying than a slow website, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Paul is there anyway I can message you? I have a few questions

Comment: @user3115600 I updated my profile so you should be able to see how to contact me. Please feel free to do so if your questions are directly related to the code I submitted. However, if your questions are general, you should ask them on SO :)

Comment: @Paul ah its a specific question, otherwise its noted and I'll ask general ones on here. I've emailed you!